# Firebase productItem names for Swift Package

Tags: firebase, swift-package-manager

I am thinking about writing a Swift Package to help me with my Firebase projects and the signup / authentication etc. process for iOS. When building the package, part of the `PackageDescription` requires you to list `productItems` dependencies. This example from the docs shows `FirebaseAuth`, I want to include `Storage`, `Firestore` and the `Swift-Beta` items as well. Where can I find the correct spelling of those `productItem` names?

```swift
  .target(
    name: "MyTargetName",
    dependencies: [
      .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "Firebase"),
      // ...
    ]
  ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the product identifiers in Firebase's [`Package.swift`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Package.swift)

Here is a sample `Package.swift` with a complete list of all the products:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "FirebaseSPMTest2",
  platforms: [.iOS(.v11), .macOS(.v10_12), .tvOS(.v10), .watchOS(.v7)],
  products: [
    // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
    .library(
      name: "FirebaseSPMTest2",
      targets: ["FirebaseSPMTest2"]),
  ],
  dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    .package(name: "Firebase", url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git", from: .init("8.0.0"))
  ],
  targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .target(
      name: "FirebaseSPMTest2",
      dependencies: [
        .product(name: "FirebaseAnalytics", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseAnalyticsSwift-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseAnalyticsSwift-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseAuth", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseAppCheck", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseAppDistribution-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseCrashlytics", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseDatabase", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseDatabaseSwift-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseDynamicLinks", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseFirestore", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseFirestoreSwift-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseFunctions", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseInAppMessaging-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseInAppMessagingSwift-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseInstallations", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseMessaging", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseMLModelDownloader", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebasePerformance", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseRemoteConfig", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseStorage", package: "Firebase"),
        .product(name: "FirebaseStorageSwift-Beta", package: "Firebase"),
      ]),
    .testTarget(
      name: "FirebaseSPMTest2Tests",
      dependencies: ["FirebaseSPMTest2"]),
  ]
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Takse a lot of time to figure out that in 10.19.0，the spm file should use like this

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "your name Commons ...",

        .package(url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git",from: "10.19.0"),
        
    ],
    targets: [

        .target(
            name: sub modules name here,
            dependencies: [
                .product(name: "FirebaseAnalytics", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseCrashlytics", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebaseMessaging", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
                .product(name: "FirebasePerformance", package: "firebase-ios-sdk"),
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**